Is docker daemon process shown in htop represents the daemon itself
I look at this screenshot:

Am I correct to assume that the CPU consumption that is showed by /usr/bin/dockerd is applicable to the docker daemon itself, not the processes that run inside the containers managed by the docker? For example, the /usr/bin/clickhouse-server process runs inside the container, but it's shown as a separate entry in the table.

Yes, your assumption is spot on! The CPU usage you’re seeing for /usr/bin/dockerd is just for the Docker daemon itself, which manages all your containers. It doesn’t include the processes running inside the containers.
Each containerized process, like the /usr/bin/clickhouse-server in your case, is shown separately in the list because even though it’s running in a container, it’s still a process on the system. So, the resource usage for clickhouse-server is tracked individually, just like any other process.
Basically, when Docker runs a container, it uses the host’s kernel to manage processes. Each containerized process runs in its own namespace, and it’s treated like other processes by the host system, which is why tools like top or ps can see them. These processes have separate PIDs inside the container and on the host, which explains why dockerd and clickhouse-server appear as separate entries.
This is a good resource that explains how containers are managed and how their processes are visible on the host system.
https://www.baeldung.com/linux/docker-container-process-host-pid
Hope this helps.
